# Speeding up 3D graph computation postions

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have application used to display 3D graphs. To calculate the position of each node I am using Force directed graph algorithm with Quadtree (or more precisely octree) used to optimize it. Display is handled by OpenGL.

However, I am not sure if this is the best sort of algorithms for my task. I found it used for some tasks with small number of nodes but not with bigger (like thousands of nodes). According to papers I've read Force directed graph is O(n^2) algorithm and using octree it should be reduced to O(nlogn).

It looks like the optimization is working but my dataset consist of thousands of nodes and visualization at a level of about 1 200 nodes takes very long time to compute positions of each node for each frame. What's more my dataset is random, so nodes that are connected with one another might be loaded in different time so the distance between them might be significant.

Can someone advice what other algorithm I can use to achieve this task in reasonable time? Maybe there is some other approach that is not so node-number dependent?